# print a term but without linking it

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to print a nodes term, the code below works and it specifies which vocab ID. But I don't want the term to link to the term list. How do I remove the link. And can this be simplified and without the ul list?

```
<?php  if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) ) {
$node = node_load(arg(1));
$vid = 7;
$terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, $vid);
if ($terms) {print '<ul>'; foreach ($terms as $term) 
{print '<li>'.l($term->name,'taxonomy/term'.$term->tid).'</li>'; }
print '</ul>'; 
}}?>
```

Comment: you have a function named l that outputs the html for a link, edit\remove that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply remove l() function

```
<?php  if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) ) {
$node = node_load(arg(1));
$vid = 7;
$terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, $vid);
if ($terms) {print '<ul>'; foreach ($terms as $term) 
{print '<li>'.$term->name.'</li>'; }
print '</ul>'; 
}}?>
```